# Macbook Air M1 Display Issue

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-silicon

[image: this is the issue]

Any idea what's the problem??
it was working absolutely fine suddenly became like this.

Comment: Were there any people around when it happened?

Comment: Nope .. display is gone .. working with external monitor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ouch!
That's a smashed screen, I'm afraid.

You can see the impact point & the cracks radiating outwards…

[image]

Quite often these are caused by closing the lid with something trapped inside, rather than actually being struck by something when the lid is open.